Does the practice of Tibetan Buddhism reconcile with early Buddhist teachings?
Does the practice of Tibetan Buddhism reconcile with early Buddhist teachings? I have read a lot of books in that tradition, and it seems to me that it is; but it would be helpful to gain some insight from others.

Difficult to understand in which way you meant the word reconcile?
For simplistic sake I can say from my experience some Tibetan Buddhist teachings and practices are in line with the original Buddhas teachings, but they are also amalgamated with latter teachings not from the Buddha, or accepted by the continuous sangha as the words of the Buddha.
The difference here is more of a cultural issue, where Tibetans believe things such as the 3 bodies of the Buddha and that the Buddha and his words can be spoken through other people. Too complex for this question but called the Trikaya This is of course not taught by the Buddha, though used by Tibetan and other religious sects as justification why words not spoken by the Buddha "are" spoken by the Buddha.
A personal example is that when I originally sought out teachings from Buddhists I found a Tibetan sect and like most Tibetan sects their fundamental teachings is the practice of Lamrim. Now while I studied under them, I already had understanding, even just intellectually, of the original Buddhas teachings. 4 noble truths and 8 fold path specifically. I myself cross referenced the teachings on Lamrim and found it to be in line with the 8 fold path (as well as the commentary explained the 4 noble truths) specifically in the form of the 3 higher trainings
What I didn't know at the time, because my understanding(s) were all intellectual is that the 7 tranquil abiding teachings within Lamrim is in fact "only" samatha meditation, where I thought concentration/sati/samatha/jhana were synonymous. Now after more practice and explicatively more study I realised that these tranquillity teachings were in fact what is known as access concentration, which were NOT taught by the Buddha (specifically) but taught by buddhaghosa in the visuddimagga.
Which of course would leave my earlier cross reference of the 3 higher trainings in Lamrim being "incorrect"
After re-examining I clearly found out Lamrim is not actually fully in line with the 8 fold path, as there is no jhana meditation, no higher concentration meditation in the method. Though in this sect (gelug) they also practice mahamudra, or at least some form of it and in those teachings there is kasina meditations, which are parts of jhana meditations.
Essentially the form might change, like the simile of the raft but the meaning may still be the same and the same results may arise if practised. I cannot say for sure. What I can say for sure is that teachings that are both from the original Buddhas teachings passed down by the sangha, as well as latter teachers and different cultural teachings (Hinduism for simplicity) have also crept into such sects teachings and are often taught as they were the Buddhas teachings..
Examples being, heart sutra, lotus sutra, perfection of wisdom sutras, diamond sutra and vast amounts of different teachers like the mahasiddhas, langri tangpa, nagarajuna, atisha, shantideva....list goes on.

Paragraph 40 of Atisha's Lamrim https://www.lamrim.com/atishalamp/LampForThePath.PDF refers to calm abiding and the Collection Of Meditative Stabilization Chapter.   The later here https://84000.co/translation/toh10/UT22084-029-001-chapter-15#UT22084-029-001-chapter-2 refers to the Noble Eightfold Path and the four concentrations (jhana) defined the same as the Pali texts, here: https://84000.co/translation/toh10/UT22084-029-001-chapter-15#UT22084-029-001-1620

Stanza 41 of the atishas lamp (link) implies that the calm abidings naturally lead to the higher absorptions, jhana, though the methods of the meditations are different. As I said above from the sect I learned from, the kasina meditations were taught in mahamudra teachings. Tranquil abiding being samatha and the kasina meditations being the jhana meditations.

A sect does not necessary represent Atisha. Refer to my comment & post.

Both Theravada & Tibetan Buddhism contain aspects of the Early Buddhist teachings but also contain both misinterpretations of & departures from the early Buddhist teachings.
My impression (from my brief studies at a Tibetan centre) is Atisha's Lamrin is the most core Tibetan Buddhism teaching. Paragraph 40 of Atisha's Lamrin refers to the (The Perfection of Wisdom in Eighteen Thousand Lines) chapter on Meditative Stabilization, which refers to and defines the Noble Eightfold Path in essentially the same manner as Early Buddhism; including the Four Jhana.
An example of a departure from Early Buddhist teachings is the doctrine of saving all sentient beings. This is the opposite of the early Buddhist teachings, which say in many places (such as Dhp 174) only a "few" will be saved.


Those persons who, from the suffering
In their own being, truly wish
To fully end all miseries
Of others are supreme.

“I’ll take no delight in quickly gaining
Enlightenment for myself.
With just one being as a reason,
I’ll stay until the end of time.

“I’ll purify inconceivable,
Limitless numbers of realms.
I’ll be remembered by my name,
Which will remain in the ten directions.



Another example of a departure is the doctrine of non-conceptuality/non-thought as Nirvana. While these distinctions are quite subtle, in early Buddhism it is the elimination of craving & self-being-conceptualisation (both inwardly & outwardly) that is Nirvana. While non-conceptually/non-thought or "the signless/themeless" is certainly a state of liberation in Early Buddhism, it is not held to be the foremost liberation (MN 43).


The character of this existence,
Born from thought, is thought.
Therefore abandoning all thought
Is the supreme nirvana.

Accordingly, the Bhagavan has also said:

"Thought—the great ignorance—makes us
Fall into the ocean of samsara.
Resting in thought-free samadhi,
Nonthought is clear as the sky.”

From the Dharaṇi of Entering Nonthought as well:

“When the victors’ children, without thought,
Contemplate the True Dharma,
They transcend thoughts so hard to escape
And eventually achieve nonthought.”

Atisha. The Lamp for the Path to Enlightenment

